# how to highlight the current user in the leaderboard

Tags: php, html

I have developed a leaderboard page thats consists username and points. I wanted to highlight the details of the `Session_user` in the table. Can someone help me with this.

my leaderboard page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
$rankname= $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<body>
    <?php
      $selectrank = "SELECT username,sum_score, FIND_IN_SET(sum_score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( sum_score ORDER BY sum_score DESC ) FROM users )) AS rank FROM users WHERE username =  '$rankname'";
      $selectuserrank= mysqli_query($db,$selectrank);
      $ranking= mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectuserrank)
      ?>
 <h4>Your rank is #<?php echo $ranking['rank'];  ?> with score: <?php echo $ranking['sum_score']  
 ?>

<table class="fixed_header">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Rank</th>
  <th>User</th>
  <th>Points</th>

 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php

$highscore = "SELECT username, score, sum_score FROM users ORDER BY sum_score DESC LIMIT 10";
$gethighscore=mysqli_query($db,$highscore);
$rank = 1;

if (mysqli_num_rows($gethighscore)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gethighscore)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo strtoupper("<td>{$rank}</td>
       <td>{$row['username']}</td>
       <td>{$row['sum_score']}</td>");
       echo "</tr>";
    $rank++;
  }
}


?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

The above displays the leaderboard of all the users. What I want, is to highlight the row of the session user in the table. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print your your users you can compare the user id with the logged user id in your session like this

```
if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $row['id']){
// do something
}
```

> make sure that you save the logged user `id` in `session`

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($gethighscore)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gethighscore)) {
  if($row[id] == $_SESSION['userid']){
    echo "<tr style='background-color:#CCC'>";
      echo strtoupper("<td>{$rank}</td>
        <td>{$row['username']}</td>
        <td>{$row['sum_score']}</td>");
    echo "</tr>";
  }else{
   echo "<tr>";
      echo strtoupper("<td>{$rank}</td>
        <td>{$row['username']}</td>
        <td>{$row['sum_score']}</td>");
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  $rank++;
}
}
```

Comment: i tried with the code you suggested , but i get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'background' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: obs i apologize add it in single quote instead of double

Comment: Joseph now, it highlights all the names in the table, I have only the row of the session user to be highlighted